# Aligning search results with css

Tags: php, html, css

Ok so I have a while loop and I want three items across per row. I tried to use the `column-count: 3;` it did not work! I also tried to limit a containing div to 702px and made the div class box 234px 234*3=702 still did not work!(just to let you know the containing div has the css of `display: table;` Here is what it looks like: http://postimg.org/image/t262vsymr/ as you can see it just keeps going across.

Here is the PHP:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_results)) {
$title = $row['title'];
$img = $row['imagename'];
$price = $row['price'];


echo "<div class=\"box\"><img class=\"results\" src=\"uimg/$img\"/><br />$title<br />$$price<br /></div>";

 }
```

My CSS:

```
.results{
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
border-radius: 2px;
padding-top:30px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;


 }
  .box{
    width: 234px;
    display: table-cell;
 }
```

Thank You To Anyone Who Can Help!

Comment: are you sure about the $$ in $$price?

Comment: yea it works because if the variable $price is 500 it prints out $500

Comment: oh yeah. have you tried making the divs "float: left" and "clear: left" every fourth one + "overflow: hidden" on the container div?

Comment: Not sure how I would do that every fourth one. I can only get it to do it every time it goes through the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so not sure if this is how you'd like to do it, but here's my take on it:

```
echo "<div class=\"box\">";
$row_items = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_results)) {
    $title = $row['title'];
    $img = $row['imagename'];
    $price = $row['price'];
    $row_items++;

    switch ($row_items) {
        case 1:
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><img class=\"results\" src=\"uimg/$img\"/><br />$title<br />$$price<br /><td>";
            break;
        case 2:
            echo "<td><img class=\"results\" src=\"uimg/$img\"/><br />$title<br />$$price<br /><td>";
            break;
        case 3:
            echo "<td><img class=\"results\" src=\"uimg/$img\"/><br />$title<br />$$price<br /><td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            $row_items = 0;
            break;
    }
}
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Thank you but it still wont work it looks like this http://postimg.org/image/m7sso2r3z/

Comment: CSS isn't my strong point but perhaps the limits you imposed previously are preventing 3 images being shown side-by-side now?

Comment: I got them all in a line. I am so close I am trying to do clear:both; but it wont knock two of them down

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this css:

```
.content-layout
{
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
   table-layout: fixed;
}

.content-layout-row 
{
   display: table-row;
}

.box
{
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

Then in php:

```
      echo "<div class=\"content-layout\">
               <div class=\"content-layout-row\">";



     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_results)) {
    $title = $row['title'];
    $img = $row['imagename'];
    $price = $row['price'];


    $cells = "<div class=\"box\"><img class=\"results\" src=\"uimg/$img\"/><br />$title<br />$$price<br /></div>";
    $i=0;    
    foreach($cells as $cell){
    $i++;
    echo $cell;
     if($i == 3){
            echo "</div></div><div class=\"content-layout\">
               <div class=\"content-layout-row\">";  
            $i=0;
        }
     }

}
echo "</div></div>";
```

Comment: hmm still wont work it just squishes them into702px I think your on the right track though

Comment: it squishes 5 into a row I only want three

Comment: you want only 3 or you want 3 on one row and 2 on the second row?

Comment: 3 in first 2 in second